# SP Services - Cross Browser Issues

Tags: jquery, xml, web-services, spservices

This code works perfectly in Firefox but userPerm does not get defined when running it in I.E 8.0.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).ready(function() {

$().SPServices({
 operation: "GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser",
 async: false,

 completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

 alert(xData.responseXML.xml);

 var userPerm = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("Permissions").attr("Value");
  alert("userPerm = " + userPerm);
  var nonAdminP = (33554432 & userPerm) == 33554432;
  alert("Non Admin Permissions == 33554432: " + nonAdminP);
  var adminP = userPerm == 9223372036854775807;
  alert("Admin Permissions: " + adminP);




 }
});

});

});
</script>
```

EDIT:

This is the response I get from I.E when printing

xData.responseText

http://i60.tinypic.com/33ufnt3.png

However in Firefox:

http://i62.tinypic.com/205rid.png

When I access the page directly in both browsers I have full access...

EDIT 2:

Just found this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

EDIT 3

Fiddler Response:

## Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom

1   200 HTTP    sp-coll-bbs.our-company-ag.com  /sites/000057/PropertyandSite/HealthSafety/Assets/SitRight.aspx 23,698  private, max-age=0; Expires: Wed, 29 Jan 2014 08:00:51 GMT  text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:6064
2   304 HTTP    sp-coll-bbs.our-company-ag.com  /sites/000057/SiteAssets/title.css  0   private,max-age=0; Expires: Wed, 29 Jan 2014 08:00:52 GMT       iexplore:6064
3   200 HTTP    code.jquery.com /jquery-1.9.1.js    268,503 max-age=315360000; Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT   application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8 iexplore:6064
4   304 HTTP    sp-coll-bbs.our-company-ag.com  /sites/000057/SiteAssets/CP%20Information%20Page%20Icons/60-pandSS.png  0   private,max-age=0; Expires: Wed, 29 Jan 2014 08:00:52 GMT       iexplore:6064
5   200 HTTP    code.jquery.com /ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js 436,883 max-age=315360000; Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT   application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8 iexplore:6064
6   200 HTTP    code.jquery.com /ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css  32,042  max-age=315360000; Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT   text/css    iexplore:6064
7   304 HTTP    sp-coll-bbs.our-company-ag.com  /sites/000057/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.0.min.js 0   private,max-age=0; Expires: Wed, 29 Jan 2014 08:00:52 GMT       iexplore:6064
8   304 HTTP    sp-coll-bbs.our-company-ag.com  /sites/000057/SiteAssets/default/CP_small.PNG   0   private,max-age=0; Expires: Wed, 29 Jan 2014 08:00:52 GMT       iexplore:6064
9   200 HTTP    sp-coll-bbs.our-company-ag.com  /_vti_bin/Webs.asmx 380 private, max-age=0  text/xml; charset=utf-8 iexplore:6064
10  302 HTTP    sp-coll-bbs.our-company-ag.com  /_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx    175 private, max-age=0      iexplore:6064
11  200 HTTP    sp-coll-bbs.our-company-ag.com  /_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx 3,821   private text/html; charset=utf-8    iexplore:6064

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the **webURL** parameter (before your async parameter) and specifying either your site's fully qualified domain name or relative path to your content?

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "operationname",
    webURL: "/sitepath", // <-- right here
    async: false,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        ...do stuff...
    }
});
```

(Syntax reference: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices)

Also - why do you have two copies of **$(document).ready()**? You should be able to remove the inner one.